# Conditional formatting in SSRS 2008r2

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to report writing and am trying to suppress rows that have zero data.  I need to know how to write the conditional iif statement when I have multiple columns of data.  Example

account number  account description  fy 2012 fy 2013 fy 2014 fy 2015

some accounts have zero numbers across the years and I don't want that row to show.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you hide [How to: Hide an Item (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159830%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Here's the expression

```
=IIF( Fields!yourField1.Value = 0  and Fields!yourField2.Value = 0 
  and Fields!yourField3.Value = 0  , True, False )
```